# Problem with shift register

Tags: arduino-uno, shift-register

I have a problem with the shift register 74HC595.

The sketch I use is able to enable a specific led (8 are connected).

When I enable led 0 to 7 it behaves like normally (they switch on when I enter the numbers).

However, for the led connected to pin 15 (other side of the ic, see [layout](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-cIb_uYGrRk4/U1fxdfGhy-I/AAAAAAAAADg/kcuUjMcpzD0/s1600/Region+Capture.png)) it behaves differently.
 When I switch this led on, ALL leds go off. When I retry, nothing happens. When I enable another led, after a short time (but can be seconds) the led for pin 15 is emitting light together with all others which where already enabled.

This seems like a malfunction in the IC (I checked already another led, another cable, another resistor). The only think I haven't checked is moving the IC to another position of the breadboard (that would take a lot of time since I have to rewrite everything). Is it possible I missed something or is the shift register broken?

The code to switch on a led:

```
void updateShiftRegister()
{
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, leds);
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
}
```

where leds are the indices of the leds (0..7).

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code, instead of just a snippet.  Also, if  “led 0 to 7” refers to 8 different LEDs (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7) you will need to specify which pin each of those 8 LEDs are connected to.  The question seems to say you have a ninth LED attached to Q0 on pin 15.

Comment: Showing the wiring (and also a photo of your breadboard circuit) may help invesitgae on this issue. Also, I'd be curious to see code that sets `leds` value and how `leds` variable was declared (`unsigned` Vs. `signed` may have surprising effect on your code).

Comment: Thanks for all remarks, however, what I try is finding another project (instruction) for using it and check if I have the same problem; if still do, I can post it (and make a minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly give an index (0..7) to a shift register if you want the index to represent the LED number to be switched on.
You have to build a table similar to the following:

```
byte led[8] = {
0b00000001,
0b00000010,
0b00000100,
0b00001000,
0b00010000,
0b00100000,
0b01000000,
0b10000000
};
```

and later . . .

```
shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, led[leds]);
```

where leds is a number 0..7

Comment: Or more cheaply `shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, bit(leds));`

Comment: Nice. I knew there had to be an even quicker way for such a simple mapping.

Comment: Thanks ... my example uses the shiftOut, but I will find another example and check if it also gives problems and than post the layout/full code if needed.

Comment: Somehow it seems to work, after using another scheme (although it looked exactly equal). So I'm really not sure why the problem existed; now it seems to work ... wondering if I should remove the question since  there might be useful information for others (regarding the table and shiftOut function.